# Как разместить бота на heroku?

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram-bot, heroku

Делаю по этому мануалу http://blizzy.ru/telegram/razmesaem-bota-na-platforme-heroku, только у меня бот на python

при вводе команды git push heroku master вижу следующее:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 Build Log
 -----> Failed to detect set buildpack https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
 !     Push failed
```

В чем дело? Как исправить?
Если можно, пожалуйста, объясните, как можно проще.

Comment: Ваша ссылка на мануал не работает, а очень хотелось бы! :)

Comment: Пустой файл requirements.txt есть, но как в него прописать зависимости?

Comment: [детальный пример для flask приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803761/23044)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Heroku не понял, что у вас там приложение на Python** (`Failed to detect set buildpack`), потому не знает, как его собрать и запустить, и поэтому отказывается его в таком виде принимать.

Согласно [странице о поддержке Python](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#activation), чтобы Heroku его корректно распознал, там должен быть в корне файл `requirements.txt`, хотя бы пустой (если нет зависимостей):

> The Heroku Python Support will be applied to applications only when the application has a `requirements.txt` in the root directory. Even if an application has no module dependencies, it should include an empty `requirements.txt` to document that your app has no dependencies.

То же самое указано и [в описании `heroku-buildpack-python`](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-python):

> A `requirements.txt` file must be present at the root of your application's repository.