# Настройка gunicorn на heroku хостинге `gunicorn app:app` heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed

Tags: python, heroku, gunicorn

Доброго времени суток! У меня возникли сложности при запуске простого [демо сайта](https://pythonworld.ru/web/cgi-1.html) написанного на чистом python на heroku. Мой [git](https://github.com/discipleartem/test_blog_1).
Структура:

```
test_blog_1:
     index.html #главная страница
     Procfile
     Pipfile
     requirements.txt
     runtime.txt
  cgi-bin #подпапка
    ...
    wall.py #главная страница 2
    form.py
```

Мои файлы для heroku:

- Procfile:
  web: gunicorn app:app
- Pipfile
  [requires]
  python_full_version = "python-3.6.4"
  [packages]
  gunicorn = "*"
- runtime.txt:
  python-3.6.4
- requirements.txt:
  pew==1.1.2
  pipenv==11.1.4
  psutil==5.4.3
  virtualenv==15.1.0
  virtualenv-clone==0.3.0
  gunicorn==19.7.1

Трейс логов с heroku:

```
2018-03-12T15:02:28.649810+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from 
crashed to starting
2018-03-12T15:02:31.776534+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn app:app`
2018-03-12T15:02:33.560984+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2018-03-12T15:02:33.542068+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 3
2018-03-12T15:02:33.325422+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-12 15:02:33 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:56370 (4)
2018-03-12T15:02:33.325541+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-12 15:02:33 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2018-03-12T15:02:33.324870+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-12 15:02:33 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 19.7.1
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333566+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-12 15:02:33 +0000] [8] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-03-12T15:02:33.329123+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-12 15:02:33 +0000] [8] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333569+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333571+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, i
n spawn_worker
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333573+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333574+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 1
26, in init_process
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333576+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333577+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 1
35, in load_wsgi
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333579+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333581+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, i
n wsgi
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333583+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333585+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65
, in load
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333586+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333588+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52
, in load_wsgiapp
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333590+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333598+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333591+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in i
mport_app
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333592+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2018-03-12T15:02:33.333709+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-12 15:02:33 +0000] [8] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 8)
2018-03-12T15:02:33.344973+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-12 15:02:33 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349379+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-12 15:02:33 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349382+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349385+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 578, i
n spawn_worker
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349387+00:00 app[web.1]:     worker.init_process()
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349389+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 1
26, in init_process
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349390+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.load_wsgi()
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349392+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 1
35, in load_wsgi
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349394+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349396+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, i
n wsgi
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349398+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.callable = self.load()
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349399+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 65
, in load
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349401+00:00 app[web.1]:     return self.load_wsgiapp()
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349403+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52
, in load_wsgiapp
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349405+00:00 app[web.1]:     return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349408+00:00 app[web.1]:     __import__(module)
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349407+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 352, in i
mport_app
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349486+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-12 15:02:33 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2018-03-12T15:02:33.464112+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-12 15:02:33 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
2018-03-12T15:02:33.349410+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app'
2018-03-12T15:02:33.463988+00:00 app[web.1]: [2018-03-12 15:02:33 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2018-03-12T15:02:36.027294+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=aqueous-bayou-99527.her
okuapp.com request_id=9df8f501-9335-4eb4-8fcf-077936807eaa fwd="176.37.205.48" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=http
s
2018-03-12T15:02:36.621802+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=aqueous-bayo
u-99527.herokuapp.com request_id=08866817-6055-4a0f-a33f-afb5e36fb1a8 fwd="176.37.205.48" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= pr
otocol=https
```

При выполнении команды `heroku ps:scale web=1`

```
Scaling dynos... done, now running web at 1:Free
```

При выполнении команды `heroku ps`

```
Free dyno hours quota remaining this month: 544h 38m (99%)
For more information on dyno sleeping and how to upgrade, see:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dyno-sleeping

=== web (Free): gunicorn app:app (1)
web.1: crashed 2018/03/12 17:06:56 +0200 (~ 7m ago)
```

**Я думаю что проблема в настройке Procfile для gunicorn и возможно отсутствии routing файла** . Мне нужно вызывать index.html при запуске сайта (из корня приложения) а так же файл wall.py (при ручном вводе в адресной строке) из папки cgi-bin. Просьба помочь в поиске и решении ошибок.

Comment: @jfs Я все делал по руководству. И нет, локально запускать не пробывал так как у меня Windows и gunicorn не установиться + я не знаю как.

Comment: @jfs специально для вас я заново повторил все действия из туторитала. Как и ожидалось ничего не изменилось. То что вы видели локальные шаги - это не означает что там был "локальный запуск", а значит что я сделал все так как и описал.

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста структуру проекта на гитхабе. У меня есть 2 главные страницы index.html и wall.py в папке cgi-bin. И нету никакого роутинг файла. Может из-за этого ? Посмотрите еще пожалуйста правильность настройки Procfile

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/74380/discussion-between-discipleartem-and-jfs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Структура проекта в коде в вопросе неправильная. `gunicorn app:app` указывает, что должен быть определён модуль `app`, который содержит `app` глобальную переменную (wsgi-приложение)—в коде в вопросе нет ни `app` модуля ни wsgi-приложения (есть по-видимому только cgi-скрипты, что другое).

Чтобы освоиться, попробуйте [создать и развернуть hello-world flask-приложение на heroku](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started):

```bsh
mkdir hello-world && cd hello-world  # директория под проект
heroku login  # нужна [бесплатная] учётная запись на Heroku 

# ставим зависимости
pipenv --python 3.6   # $ pip install pipenv
pipenv install flask gunicorn  
pipenv shell

# пишем приложение
cat >app.py<<'EOF'
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return 'Hello, World!'
EOF

# пишем как запускать сервер
echo 'web: gunicorn app:app --log-file=-' >Procfile

# проверяем локально (http :5000)
heroku local  # Ctrl+C чтобы остановить

# помещаем в систему контроля версий 
git init && git add . && git commit -m 'initial commit'

# публикуем на heroku
heroku create
git push heroku master

# проверяем (смотрим в браузере)
heroku open
```

[image: tty session]

Вот похожая инструкция с видео: https://heroku.com/python

Инструкция написана, используя bash синтаксис. На Windows, чтобы локально запускать (`heroku local -f Procfile.windows`), можно в `Procfile.windows` файле написать (не тестировано):

```bsh
web: flask run -p %PORT%
```

записав в `.env` файл:

```bsh
FLASK_APP=app.py
```

Comment: @discipleartem 1- слова "чистый Питон" означают отсутсвие Си зависимостей типа numpy. 2- Не вижу какое отношение ваш комментарий имеет к вопросу, в котором явно не stdlib модуль упоминается  (gunicorn). 3- Не вижу особого смысла, но вы можете отдельный вопрос задать: "как написать веб-приложение используя только стандартную библиотеку» упомяните с чем связано это ограничение, что вы этим хотите достичь. 4- Этот комментарий также как и ответ ничего не советует, а просто информирует (это тонкое отличие, если не ясно, то не обращайте внимания).