# Не получается Deploy бота на Heroku

Tags: python, telegram, heroku, бот

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (12/12), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 6.65 KiB | 1.66 MiB/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/python.tgz
remote:        More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-failure
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to desolate-shore-10621.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/desolate-shore-10621.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/desolate-shore-10621.git'
```

Comment: стрелка: `----->` указывает на проблему (значит что структура вашего проекта НЕ похожа на ожидаемую структуру для Питон проектов на heroku. Чтобы освоиться, начните с вводного руководства (добейтесь чтобы hello world работало, затем по шагам изменяйте, чтобы нужное вас приложение получить пока не сломается на каком-то шаге —тогда новый вопрос задайте)

Comment: [рабочий пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803761/23044)