# Развертывание Python бота Discord на Heroku

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6, discord-api

Хочу разместить дискорд бота написанном на rewrite, а не на обычном discord.py, но кажется, что Heroku использует как-раз обычный discord.py поэтому бот не запускается. Как исправлять? Может надо что-то изменить в  пипфайле(ниже)?

```
[[source]]

url = "https://pypi.python.org/simple"
verify_ssl = true


[packages]

django = "*"
gunicorn = "*"
django-heroku = "*"
discord = "*"



[requires]

python_version = "3.6"
```

UPD: Проблему решил, путём записи в requirements:

-e git+https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py@rewrite#egg=discord.py[voice]

Comment: вот посмотрите [пошаговую инструкцию для flask-приложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803761/23044). Попробуйте написать такую же для [минимального примера бота](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/quickstart.html#a-minimal-bot): какие шаги выполнили, где застряли, что на экране видите.

Comment: если думаете, что нашли решение, то опубликуйте его как свой ответ (см. кнопка "отправить ответ" ниже) -- [это явно приветствуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). Не помещайте ответы в вопросы.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

О, это забавно, я сам где-то неделю мучился с Heroku, крч все просто, не в зависимости от того юзаеш ли те репозиторий github-а или dropbox, не важно
У тебя должна быть папка с ботом, т.е:

```
BOT.py
procces_file.py
config.py
Procfile
requirements.txt
runtime.txt
```

тебе должны быть интересы только 3 файла:
1. это Procfile туда ты должен вписать просто своего бота, в моём случае это: worker: BOT.py.
2. requirements.txt туда надо вписать как минимум:

```
discord.py (или свой API)
aiohttp
websockets
chardet
```

а дальше просто впиши еще библиотеки которые ты используешь в своём боте.
3. runtime.txt: python-3.6.4 (или свою версию пайтона)

Я точно не знаю насчет библиотек, но heroku в принципе поддерживает python приложения, поэтому думаю что проблем у тебя возникнуть не должно)

Comment: А что, если мне нужен discord.py именно 1.0.0а версии? Потому что Heroku загружает именно 0.16.6 , чего мне не нужно