# Почему приложение Flask работает на localhost но отказывается работать в облаке на pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, flask, pythonanywhere

Доброго времени суток! Не судите строго, я еще совсем зелёный. Приложение нормально функционирует на localhost , но в вебе не работает. Ошибок не выдаёт, но возвращает пустой список: http://hellsbells6.pythonanywhere.com/

Код

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/' )
@app.route('/fastlinkform' )
def form_page():
    return render_template('fastlinkform.html', the_title='ENTER URL')

@app.route('/flresult', methods=['POST',] )
def result_page():
    url = request.form['url']
    res = []
    def get_html (url):
        response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        return response.read()
    def parse (html):
        soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
        tagid = soup.find_all( id=True)
        for elm in tagid:
            res.append(url +'#' + elm.attrs['id'])

    def main():
        parse(get_html(url))


    if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()

    return str(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
        app.run(debug=True)
```

в чем может быть причина??

---

Убрал лишнее:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/' )
@app.route('/fastlinkform' )
def form_page():
    return render_template('fastlinkform.html', the_title='ENTER URL')

@app.route('/flresult', methods=['POST',] )
def result_page():
    url = request.form['url']
    res = []
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    page = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    tagid = soup.find_all( id=True)
    for elm in tagid:
        res.append(url +'#' + elm.attrs['id'])

    return str(res)
```

Сервер стал возвращать ошибку `urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden`

Попробовал передать юзер агент:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import urllib.request
from urllib.request import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
class AppURLopener(urllib.request.FancyURLopener):
    version = "Mozilla/5.0"

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/' )
@app.route('/fastlinkform' )
def form_page():
    return render_template('fastlinkform.html', the_title='ENTER URL')

@app.route('/flresult', methods=['POST',] )
def result_page():
    url = request.form['url']
    res = []
    opener = AppURLopener()
    response = opener.open(url)
    page = response.read()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
    tagid = soup.find_all( id=True)
    for elm in tagid:
        res.append(url +'#' + elm.attrs['id'])

    return str(res)
```

Теперь я получаю ошибку `ValueError: read of closed file`
На localhost все версии кода работают как ожидается, плиз хелп!

Comment: Зачем вы объявляете функции внутри функции и что у вас забыл `if __name__ == '__main__'` внутри функции? Из-за этого и не работает скорее всего

Comment: @ВикторСмольский, условие `__name__ == '__main__'` истинно, когда вы запускаете модуль из командной строки, и ложно, когда модуль импортируется. На сервере скорее всего модуль импортируется, из-за чего `main()` не вызывается. Просто уберите внутри функции проверку `if __name__ == '__main__'`.

Comment: @insolor: https://help.pythonanywhere.com/pages/Flask/

Comment: начните с hello-world примера, с вводного руководства. Что-нибудь вроде [примера для heroku](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/803761/23044)

Comment: @jfs, так, и как это противоречит тому, что нужно убрать проверку `if __name__ == '__main__': main()` внутри функции? Или как понимать то что вы молча дали эту ссылку?

Comment: конечно, внутри функции много чего убрать надо. Ссылка о том, что это может быть не достаточно.

Answer (score 2):

Заработало! Дело было в акке pythonanywhere.com, на бесплатном акке нельзя обращаться к внешним сайтам :)